# PowerBuilder Dynamically Name Object

Tags: dynamic, powerbuilder

I have several picturebuttons, a1, b1, c1.. so on.. to h8..

I am using this for loop.

```
FOR i = 1 TO 6

    FOR j = 1 TO 8

        s_obj = CharA(96 + j) + String(i)

        l_found = ds_list.Find( "pos = '" + s_obj+ "'", 1, l_rows)

        IF l_found > 0 THEN

        ELSE
//      s_obj.  Text = ""
//
        END IF

    NEXT

NEXT
```

I would like to change the text of the Picture Button and the Tag of that Picture Button without doing CHOOSE CASE "a1" etc.

Is there a way to shorten my code that when I get "a1" i can do a1.text = "Blah"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with window controls (not without a PBNI extension, which I believe would get you there, or a loop through the window.Control[] array to find the control with a ClassName() that matches s_obj), but if you put your controls into a DataWindow, and changed your text assignment to a Modify() (e.g. `dw.Modify(s_obj + ".text='foo'")`)

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: i have though so. its so sad describe/ modify only works for datawindows. Anyhow, I need picture buttons to make my Module work. I cannot see picture buttons in Insert in PB 12

Comment: Are you saying you don't see PictureButtons in DataWindows? Pictures can be added to Buttons in DataWindows (Picture File property in Properties pane), but there isn't a distinct PictureButton control.